# PHP: Stripe API Getting useful error as simple texts string?

Tags: php

I'm using Stripe PHP API.

Everything works fine. However, I need to get/catch the errors that is returned by Stripe API as a simple readable texts string.

Currently my code prints out errors like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\Card' with message 'Your card's security code is invalid.' in /var/www/...
```

-

What I need is only this:

```
Your card's security code is invalid.
```

This is my entire code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require_once('stripe/init.php');


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_345345345345345345345");

$result = \Stripe\token::create(array(
    "card" => array(
      "name" => 'David', "number" => '4242424242424242', "exp_month" => '12', "exp_year" => '2019', "cvc" => '37674'
    )
  ));

$token = $result['id'];

echo $token;

try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => "7000", // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "usd", "card" => $token, "description" => "test@test.com"
      ));
    echo 'success';
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // Card was declined.
    $e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
    $error = $e_json['error'];

    echo $error;
}

?>
```

Please note that this doesn't do anything:

```
catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // Card was declined.
        $e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
        $error = $e_json['error'];

        echo $error;
        }
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've tried everything and it is very frustrating that nothing works at all.

The catch does nothing and when i run my PHP page, it is always empty/blank when in fact it should have the error in it:

```
require_once('stripe/init.php');


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_345345345345345345345");

$result = \Stripe\token::create(array(
    "card" => array(
      "name" => 'David', "number" => '4242424242424242', "exp_month" => '12', "exp_year" => '2019', "cvc" => '37674'
    )
  ));

$token = $result['id'];

echo $token;

try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => "7000", // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "usd", "card" => $token, "description" => "test@test.com"
      ));
    echo 'success';
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original:**

Try this,..

```
$e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
$err = $e_json['error'];
$error = $err['message'];
```

**Updated:**

Here's my full, working, code. (minus code related to my site and DB)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">Stripe.setPublishableKey("' . STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY . '");</script>';
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_SESSION['token'] == $token)) {
       $errors['token'] = 'You have apparently resubmitted the form. Please do not do that.';
    }
    else {
       $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    }
}
else {
  $errors['token'] = 'The order cannot be processed.';
}

if (empty($errors)) {
 try {
  require_once('lib/Stripe.php');
  Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);
  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $amount,"currency" => "usd","card" => $token,"description" => "charge for $email"));
  // get objects like $charge->id and add them to your DB.
 } 
 catch (Stripe_CardError $e) { // Card was declined.
   $e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
   $err = $e_json['error'];
   $errors['stripe'] = $err['message'];
 } 
}
```

About all I left out is my require config.inc.php, the code related to my service/DB, and things like `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` at the end of the file.

HTML:

```
<form action="charge" method="POST">
  <script
     src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
     data-key="pk_live_bRdpwmwordnr8riwowkr4K0pd"
     data-amount="495"
     data-label="Credit Card"
     data-name=" MY COOL SERVICE"
     data-description="Subscription ($4.95)"
     data-billing-address="true"
     data-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stripe-uploads/acct_KKcoolThismerchant-icon-780050592-icon128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: @DavidHope, I have updated my answer to give you my full Stripe code, minus 'my site related code'.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not using a Stripe form. Everything's done server side. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since `\Stripe\Error\Card` is a subclass of `\Exception` you can call `getMessage()` method to get exception message

```
catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also note that exception occurs much earlier on your code, in this place:

```
$result = \Stripe\token::create(array(
    "card" => array(
      "name" => 'David', "number" => '4242424242424242', "exp_month" => '12', "exp_year" => '2019', "cvc" => '37674'
    )
  ));
```

To catch this exception you should place `try {` before call to `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_345345345345345345345");`

Comment: doesn't do anything.